# React helmet not showing meta tags in view page source but shows in element on inspect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We have this web and we added meta tags in different pages using this way.

```
<Helmet>
 <title>THIS IS TITLE</title>
 <meta
  name="description" 
  content="THIS IS CONTENT" />
</Helmet>
```

I see the change in title when I hit the route for this page. I see meta tags in elements but I don't see meta tags of that page in view page source. What's wrong and how can we solve this. As per our seo expert, it should come in view page source.

Note: It is a client side rendered app.

Answer (score 9):

This is because react (and react-helmet) are front-end tools (unless you are doing server side rendering) and the view source browser's feature is showing you the original source downloaded from the server, while the "inspect" action is displaying the actual DOM.

What this means?

Your users will see new meta tags normally, and so Google Bot (as recently started to execute JavaScript) but not other crawling service or search engines.

If you want to target other search engines: do SSR.

Comment: If i understand you correctly,never mind when we dont see helmet header in page source,google see it?

Comment: @Goran_Ilic_Ilke roughly speaking: yes. Just be sure it's in the generated code

Answer (score 0):

you can change meta data in viewsource code also all you need to do is that after the build is completed change index.html to index.php and add another file called metas.php

in metas.php you can simple write php code like this

```
<?php
$url =  "https://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";
$escaped_url = htmlspecialchars( $url, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );


if ($escaped_url === 'https://example.com') {
    $pageTitle = 'title';
    $metaDescription = 'some text';
    $canonical ='https://example.com';
} 


else if ($escaped_url === 'https://example.com') {
    $pageTitle = 'title';
    $metaDescription = 'some text';
    $canonical ='https://example.com';
} 
else{
    $pageTitle = '404';
    $metaDescription = 'some text';
    $canonical ='https://example.com';

}
?>
```

and in you index.php include the metas.php file on top and call these variables which is in the metas.php file like this:-

```
<title><?php echo $pageTitle; ?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $metaDescription; ?>" />
<link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo $canonical; ?>">
```