# React Helmet Async is not updating the meta description

Tags: reactjs, meta-tags, react-helmet

I'm attempting to use React Helmet async to change the title and meta tag of a React app's client-side rendering at runtime. I can change the title, but not the meta tag.

My code on index.html is

```
 <title>my title</title>
<meta
  name="description"
  content="test description"
/>
```

My code on one of the pages

```
<Helmet>
<title>{title}</title>
<meta name='description' content={description} />
</Helmet>
```

I wrap app.js with helmet provider as

```
 <HelmetProvider>
   <App/>
 </HelmetProvider>
```

Please help me to fix this issue, or you can suggest other methods or packages to update the meta description. I am using React and React-dom version 17.0.2.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76341661/16576627
check this link to update metadata and title dynamiclly

Answer (score 1):

Write `data-rh="true"` in `meta` tag inside `index.html` e.g,

```
<meta name="description" content="test description" data-rh="true" />
```

and then inspect HTML to see changes.

Comment: couldn't find any documentation for this except for a [github issue](https://github.com/staylor/react-helmet-async/issues/108)